# accessing *nix file system through django

Tags: linux, django

I have a django project installed in `/home/user/project`. And have strokes in code, processing files in file system. If i make new directory
`os.makedirs('crowdin_temp')` it is created within django project folder. If i make os.system commands with file system (like `os.system("rm crowdin_temp/" + file_name)`) the file within project directory are visible. It makes me feel that only django project folder is visible. Is it possible to process files outside of project folder? (e.g. in `/home/user/` directory)

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question with an [MVCE code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think that if you want to do `os.system("rm -rf /")` from within Django, that is totally possibly. Provided the user running Django (which in case of a production setup probably is a 'nobody' user or similar) has permissions to do this. The trick is to use the full path; your example(s) don't show the use of the full path, but use a relative path instead. *But*, the example in this comment also tells you why it's probably a bad idea to manipulate the file system from within Django.

Comment: @Evert yes, it worked with full paths, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you specify full path?

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> import os
>>> os.makedirs('/tmp/temp')
>>> os.system('touch /tmp/temp/somefile')
0
>>> os.system('rm /tmp/temp/somefile')
0
```